# How to create authentication (email-token/digest) link when two models are involved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, railstutorial.org

I've been following railstutorial.org. In this tutorial we a.o. learn how to create a token/digest together with a mailer for account activation. It saves a digest to the db and sends an email with a link that contains a token + email address. An authentication controller method then checks the email-token combination against the digest in the db.

Now I have a similar situation but with a complicating factor: There are `users` and `organizations`. My use case is that an organization can invite a user to become a member of that organization. The user will need to confirm this using an authentication link, before the user actually becomes a member of that organization.

Below is my current setup, which consists of a digest being saved to the `User` table and a link with the user's email address and token. The problem is that if the user clicks the authentication link, the authentication method still does not know to which organization it should add the user. It only has an email address and token.

How can I achieve that it is known which organization sent the invitation? Also, we of course don't want the user to be able to manipulate the link in such a way that the user can add himself to a different organization than the one the user was invited for.

---

Controller method:

```
def request
  @organization = current_organization
  @user = User.find(email: params[:user][:email])
  @user.send_invitation(@organization)
end
```

Model method:

```
def send_invitation(organization)
  create_invite_digest  # Uses other model method to create digest and token.
  update_columns(invite_digest: self.invite_digest)
  UserMailer.add_user(self, organization).deliver_now
end
```

Mailer method:

```
def add_user(user, organization)
  @user = user
  @organization = organization
  mail to: user.email, subject: "Please confirm"
end
```

Mailer View:

```
<%= adduser_url(@user.invite_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

Controller method to authenticate:

```
def adduser
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  if user && user.authenticated?(:invite, params[:id])
    user.add_role(organization)  # Should add user to organization, but then it needs to know which organization
    flash[:success] = "User added"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Model method to add user: requires information about the organization to add the user to.

```
def add_role(organization)
end
```

Comment: are you using devise gem for logins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a project I had that was similar, I had an invitation model and participant model (a membership is also a good name for this).

The invitation had a user_email, organization_id, and token.  It had a related mailer that was created when the invitation was created.

The user then would receive the invitation by email and click to see it on the site, using the token for the invitation as the find parameter.  The invitation had the opportunity to "accept", which was really the ability to create a participant record (user_id, organization_id).  The user would have to be logged in for this, which may be a new registration or sign in.  The participant would be created only if the invitation token was valid (exists and not yet used).  I have a date on the invitation "accepted_at" which is used to know its state and if it can be used to create a participant or not.  Users are not required to use a particular email address for registration, they just have to have access to the invitation to be able to accept it.  Users can be a participant only once in an organization.  The role on the participant is determined by the controller.

This all works really well for me.  I am also planning to add a participant_request model that will allow the logged in user to request to be a participant of an organization.  The organization would then have the option to view requests and "accept" or "deny" them - create the participant or decline the request.  Datetimes will be on the request to know its state.

If you want more model details, I can give those.  This may be enough to work from.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to create an Invitation model of some sort that contains the token, user_id and organization_id. This will help you keep track of the references, and allow for flexibility in the future.

You could also add extra meta that way too (e.g. accepted_at), and possibly add the ability for the invite to only be valid for a certain amount of time (by using the invitation created_at, for example).